# Pasting with overwrite in Vim

Tags: vim

I want to be able to paste something from the buffer (probably using `p`), but instead of inserting it into the text, I want to replace whatever was there before (just like the `R` command). I've searched Google, vim documentation, and Stack Overflow but could not find anything on the issue. I imagine that it's just a command that I don't know about. Any help would be appreciated.

That's all I need to know, but if you want to know my specific problem:

Essentially I'm just trying to create a short script for documentation headers. At the beginning of every function I put the following:

```
// FunctionName <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
```

However adding all those `<>` gets annoying. I want to be able to place my cursor on a function name, press the <kbd>F6</kbd> key and it produce the above. The problem, of course, is that function names are not constant sizes and it would make the "chain" look weird. So I just want to paste OVER a bunch of pre-made chain so that the whole thing will always be a constant number of characters. i.e.:

start with

```
//<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
```

Paste " FunctionName " and end with

```
// FunctionName <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
```

Comment: I think it would be easier to fill in the `<>` with something like `:s#$#\=repeat('<>', (&textwidth - len(getline('.')))/2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with this:

```
:exe "normal ".strlen(@p)."x\"pP"
```

It deletes the right number of chars, and then paste the content of register `p`.

Comment: Thanks! This works with a few changes. 

(1)The two p's I changed to 0's as yank doesn't defaultly put anything in register p, but 0 instead. Was there a reason that you used register p?

(2)I added a : before the exe to work in scripts. (This confused me for a bit but then I figured it out. I guess this is just a noob mistake on my part, but would have liked the clarification.)

(3)Added "<CR>" to the end to make it automatically return the call

Comment: I read wrong, I thought you wanted to use the 'p' register, but you were talking about the 'p' command  :)

Answer (score 34):

I found a much better solution

`R` Enter Replace mode: Each character you type replaces an existing character, starting with the character under the cursor.

So `R <ctrl-r>"` will do what you want. Note there is a space before and after `<ctrl-r>"`.

**OLD ANSWER**

You can do this with a macro pretty easily

```
qhmhA <esc>a<><esc>40.80|D`hq

qh start macro
mh set mark
A <esc> insert a space after the existing text
a<><esc> insert '<>'
40. repeat last command 40 times
80| move to column 80
D delete to the end of the line
`h jump back to mark
q end macro
```

The macro can then be repeated with `@h`. You probably want to save this to your .vimrc like so

```
let @h = 'mhA ^[a<>^[40.80|D`h'
```

Note that the `^[` are supposed to be one character entered by pressing `<ctrl-V><esc>`

Comment: Thanks! This appears to work too. I have chosen yolenoyer's answer as I feel like it is more elegant. I would upvote you, but I don't have 15 reputation yet. :(*facepalm*

Comment: Do you really need `gR`? `R<C-R>"` seems to work too

Comment: Hmm your right. I thought I had tried that and it only replaced one character with the whole pasted item, but that's not the case. Updated answer.

Comment: I consider this solution more elegant since it's constructed using basic commands. I wouldn't have been able to do yolenoyer's solution without looking up documentation

Comment: I considered yoloenoyer's more elegant because it solved the problem generally and not just my specific question. Of course this new solution is general, but I was talking about the old one.

Comment: This approach can be used with any register, e.g. `R<C-R>0` for the numbered register `"0` holding the text from the most recent yank command (the unnamed register `""` is overwritten by delete commands!) or `R<C-R>a`  for the named register `"a`.

Comment: Great answer.  I would love it if there was a solution that didn't use CTRL-R.  We have `p` and `:put`, but need some quick and easy modifiers to these which do the same thing but overwrite the number of characters (or lines) respectively.  I'm finding the linewise use case comes up somewhat often when editing config files with small differences, etc.

Comment: This does not work for blocks. It will put the following lines at the start of the line and not on the column of the cursor.

Answer (score 17):

You can use visual selection.

- `Vp` select the whole line and overwrite with buffer
- `viwp` select the word under cursor and overwrite with buffer content.
- `vi(p` overwrite what is in between parenthesis.

I particularly like that it highlights what should be overwritten, which
makes it easier to verify.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

Simply do `R` and `<C-r>0` or the 'register' you are trying to yank. If in doubt, check `:reg`

## Long answer

From `:help i_CTRL-R`:

```
    Insert the contents of a register.  Between typing CTRL-R and
    the second character, '"' will be displayed to indicate that
    you are expected to enter the name of a register.
    The text is inserted as if you typed it, but mappings and
    abbreviations are not used.  If you have options like
    'textwidth', 'formatoptions', or 'autoindent' set, this will
    influence what will be inserted.  This is different from what
    happens with the "p" command and pasting with the mouse.
    Special registers:
        '"' the unnamed register, containing the text of
            the last delete or yank
        '%' the current file name
        '#' the alternate file name
        '*' the clipboard contents (X11: primary selection)
        '+' the clipboard contents
        '/' the last search pattern
        ':' the last command-line
        '.' the last inserted text
        '-' the last small (less than a line) delete
                        *i_CTRL-R_=*
        '=' the expression register: you are prompted to
            enter an expression (see |expression|)
            Note that 0x80 (128 decimal) is used for
            special keys.  E.g., you can use this to move
            the cursor up:
                CTRL-R ="\<Up>"
            Use CTRL-R CTRL-R to insert text literally.
            When the result is a |List| the items are used
            as lines.  They can have line breaks inside
            too.
            When the result is a Float it's automatically
            converted to a String.
            When append() or setline() is invoked the undo
            sequence will be broken.
```

Comment: This answer is perfect. Short, sweet, to the point, does exactly as advertised. Someone downvoted it but that makes no sense.

Comment: I think the answer should be `R` and then `<Ctrl> R`, not `<Ctrl> 0`.