# copy and paste behavior using VIM with yiw and di"

Tags: vim

I try to copy `dog` with `yiw` and replace with `cat` using `di"` and `P`.

The problem is that when I use `di"` it overwrites the `dog` buffer.

Starting point:

```
dog
debugPrint("cat");
debugPrint("cat");
debugPrint("cat");
debugPrint("cat");
```

Expected result:

```
dog
debugPrint("dog");
debugPrint("dog");
debugPrint("dog");
debugPrint("dog");
```

I managed to get the expected result using this (but I found it too complex to repeat):

Copy `dog` to register `a` : `"ayiw` then replace `cat` using `di"` and paste with `"aP`.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do, and what happens instead?

Comment: The [ReplaceWithRegister plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/ReplaceWithRegister)  helps with that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pasting with overwrite in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413220/pasting-with-overwrite-in-vim)

Comment: most likely `yiw` -> `viwp` is what you are searching for. But honestly, just use search & replace for that... else you will have to do it on every line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the `:%s` to replace the cat with the dog since the way `di"` then `P` takes too much time.

```
:%s/cat/dog/
```